# Как сбросить значения сразу нескольких селектфилдов в плагине select2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select2

Хочу сделать кнопку сброса фильтров(в каечестве фильтров информации и используются селектфилды). Нашел  [решение для одного селектфилда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17957040/reset-select2-value-and-show-placeholder)
Решение $`("#selectId").empty().select2();` работает нормально.
Но как быть если у меня штук 5 селектфилдов? Для каждого писать сброс отдельно и повторять 5 раз empty().select2()? Можно как-то применить к этой пачке id один раз данную конструкцию?

Comment: что бы не повторять запросы, -  есть циклы http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: Создаете массив из объектов DOM ведущие к вашим селектам, и циклам делаете `.empty().select2()`. Легко поддерживать и дополнять. А как вы ещё думали, чтобы они сами чистились?) Это же контроль над компонентом, что напишите то и будет

Comment: Задайте им один класс и выбирайте по классу: `$(".resetable-select")...`

Comment: @ddeadlink через цикл,который представлен по ссылке все работает. спасибо. вас не затруднит прописать эток ак ответ на вопрос,чтобы я мог выбрать его и закрыть вопрос?

Comment: @Iga, вариант с классом от Igor изящнее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для перебора элементов вы можете использовать [циклы](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

Либо как предлагали выше, -  выбирать по классу `$('.yourClassSelector')...`